# How to test randomness of RNG using RNG test suite?

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics

I developed a RNG algorithm and It generate random numbers , Now i want to test the randomness of my generated outputs. I downloaded a test suite from nist(sts). There is an option to give input binary file to test the randomness. But i dont know how to generate these binary files. My RNG outputs 64bits length. How can i stack this outputs to generate a binary file. There is only sequence length input in the test suite. How to specify the RNG output as 64bit in test suite?.

Comment: The size of the output elements should be irrelevant. If your random numbers are good, it doesn't matter how you group the bits. Just write the numbers in binary (8 bytes per element). What programming language are you using?

Comment: C Programming, in GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the output elements should be irrelevant. If your random numbers are good, it doesn't matter how you group the bits. Just write the numbers in binary (64 bits == 8 bytes per element). The test suit will try different groupings of these bits.

Comment: I tried that you mentioned above. but it asking for sequence length of bit streams. My program generated 100 number of 64 bit number. i wrote this numbers to a binary file. What will be the sequence length of this configuration ?

Comment: Easy: 6400 bits. 800 bytes.

Comment: Hello @comocomocomocomo , I given 6400 as sequence length and selected the binary file , selected all test for given binary file then the test suite asked for "How many bitstreams ?" I gave 64 and run the test. it shows "igamc: UNDERFLOW" error. How can i overcome this error

Comment: I don't know what it means with "bitstreams", but I'd try answering 1 bitstream.

Comment: I've the same situation as you, have you found the solution on how the input should work? and the bitstream? @comocomocomocomo

Comment: Hi @Ender. Nope. Sorry